# Cannot reference SQLite database with relative path inside the ENV file of a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, environment-variables, laravel-5.7

I just created a vanilla `Laravel-React` project, referenced on the following link:

https://github.com/napolev/laravel-react-vanilla

On this project I'm usign `SQLite` instead of `MySQL`.

My problem is that when I specify a relative file path for parameter: `DB_DATABASE`, for example: `database.sqlite` I get the error I mention below. I tried placing the previous file inside both directories: `/` and `/database` with no luck. In the other hand, if I specify the full path for the previous file: `database.sqlite`, then it works properly.

This is the: `.env` file:

https://github.com/napolev/laravel-react-vanilla/blob/master/.env#L11

```
# here a preview:

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
# the following line is not working. it works with full path, though.
DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Database (database.sqlite) does not exist.
(SQL: select * from "projects" order by "created_at" desc)
```

[image]

Any idea about how can I use a relative path?, for example, the name of the file: `database.sqlite` or: `database/database.sqlite`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the laravel docs?

> The database configuration for your application is located at `config/database.php`. In this file you may define all of your database connections, as well as specify which connection should be used by default.
>
> SQLite Configuration
>   After creating a new SQLite database using a command such as  touch `database/database.sqlite`, you can easily configure your environment variables to point to this newly created database by using the database's absolute path:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
```